# $n$ is odd if and only if there exists an $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n^4=16a+1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, solution-verification

Write a formal proof.

Suppose that $n \in ℕ$. Prove $n$ is odd if and only if there exists $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n^4 = 16a + 1$.

There exists $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n=2k+1$. So I've used this formula for odd numbers
$$n^4=(2k+1)^4 = 16k^4+32k^3+24k^2+8k+1$$

since our goal is to match this to the above $n^4$,
$$n^4=8(2k^4+4k^3+3k^2+k)+1$$
unfortunately this form does not match $16a+1$

This is where I got stuck and could use help on the proof.

A random solution I thought of is below, however I'm looking for a better answer.

Let $a=2k$ ; I randomly though of a substitution.
$$n^4=8(2*16a^4+16*8a^3+3*4a^2+2a)+1$$
$$n^4=16(16a^4+64a^3+6a^2+a)+1$$
this has the form $16a+1$ with '$(16a^4+64a^3+6a^2+a)$ = an integer'.

**Note**
Thanks everyone for the help the proof totally makes sense now!
Special shoutout to @lulu and @fleablood

The part that solidified it for me was the breakdown of the 2 cases

*(3+1)2, k being even or odd!

Comment: Good start!  So all that's left is to prove that $24k^2+8k=8k\times(3k+1)$ is divisible by $16$.  For that, note that $k$ is either even or odd and  proceed accordingly.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! Just letting you know I'm thinking about what you proposed and I understand what your saying. At least for: 242+8=8×(3+1)  is divisible by 16 part. Now Im interpreting the second part: For that, note that  is either even or odd and proceed accordingly

Comment: The first two terms, $64k^4+32k^3$, are manifestly divisible by $16$ so you can ignore them.  That just leaves the $8k(3k+3)$ which isn't obviously divisible by $16$.  It is, however, obviously divisible by $8$ so all you have to do is to show that one of $k$ or $(3k+1)$ must be even.

Comment: Ahh because if k or 3k+1 must be even then the full term 8*(....) will be even and thus divisible by 16. This also explains why my proposed solution of let k =2a worked because that implies an even number.

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: "the above n^4 n^4=8(2k^4+4k^3+3k^2+k)+1 ; unfortunately this form does not match 16a+1 "  It does if $ 2k^4+4k^3+3k^2+k$ is even.

Comment: @ChawnNeal  Be careful of what you write.  It is clear that $8k(3k+1)$ is even, because it has a (visible) factor of $8$.  What you need to prove is that $k(3k+1)$ is even.  That is not instantly apparent.  That is, you can't see the factor of $2$.  But once you show that that term is even then you'll know that $8k(3k+1)$ is divisible by $16$.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. I was currently thinking one way since 8(3+1) = 2(4k(3k+1)) = 2* Integer, then its even.

Comment: If $k$ is even then $k(3k+1)$ is even.  If $k$ is odd then $3k$ is odd and $3k + 1$ is even so $(3k+1)k$ is even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is odd then there exists an integer $k$ so that $n$ can be written as $n=2k +1$. And with respect to that $k, n^4 = (2k+1)^4 = 16k^4 + 4*8k^3 + 6*4k^2 +   4k + 1=16k^4 + 32k^2 + 24k^2 + 4k +1$.

And $n^4= 16(k^4 + 2k^3 + \frac {3k^2 + k}2) + 1= 16(k^4 + 2k^3 + \frac {k(3k+1)}2) + 1$.

So if we can prove $\frac {k(3k+1)}2$ is always an integer we are done.  If $k$ is even than $\frac k2$ is an integer. and $\frac k2(3k+1)$ is an integer.  If $k$ is odd then $3k+1$ is even so $\frac {3k+1}2$ is an integer.

........

In hindsight we could have realized that if $n$ is odd then $n$ can be written as $4k \pm 1$ for some $k$ and some choose of $+/-$.

Then $n^4 = (4k \pm 1)^4 = 4^4k^4 \pm 4*4^3k^3 + 6*4^2k^2 \pm 4*4k + 1= 16(16k^4 \pm 16k^3 +6k^2 \pm k) + 1$.

And if we want to be pedantic masochists  $n^4 = 16a+1$ when $a = (\frac {n-1}2)^4 + 2(\frac {n-1}2)^3 + \frac {(n-1)(3n-1)}4$, which, as $n$ is odd is an integer.

======

That proves if $n$ is odd then there is an integer $a$ so that $n^4 = 16a + 1$.

If $n^4 = 16a+1$ then $n^4$ is odd and $n$ is odd.  (So the other direction is facile.)

Comment: Ahh so what you're saying in your proof: ' So if we can prove (3+1)2 is always an integer we are done. If  is even than /2 is an integer. and /2*(3+1) is an integer. If  is odd then 3+1 is even so 3+1/2 is an integer.' ...    if k is even k/2 will be and integer thus k/2 * (3k+1) will be an integer or if k is odd then 3k+1/2 = 6b+4/2 which would be an integer therefore we can conclude in an exhaustive test k(3k+1)/2 must be an integer?

Comment: I just learned about mathjax now, so I will learn the syntax for future writing.

Comment: $odd\times odd = odd$ and $odd + odd = even$ so $3\times odd + 1=even$.  I assumed that would be intuitive and clear.  But we you *want* to replace $k = 2b +1$ then $3k + 1 = 6b + 4$ which is clearly even.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if done in two stages:

$n^2 = (2k+1)^2 = 4k^2+4k+1 = 8\binom{k+1}{2}+1 = 8b+1$

$n^4=(8b+1)^2= 64b^2+16b+1 = 16(4b^2+b)+1 = 16a+1$